# windows 8.1 app background task cannot work after reboot

Tags: c#, background-task

We meet a issue when using background task on windows 8.1 windows app.

We found that background task which register by time trigger cannot work after reboot on Windows 8.1 device.
Before reboot device it works well which setting time trigger value is 15 minutes.

Does any guys meet same case or have any solution, thanks in advance.

**Register background task codes:**

```
await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "SampleBackgroundTask";
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Tasks.SampleBackgroundTask";
builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

return task;

**Run method codes:**

```
var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

IToastText02 toastContent = ToastContentFactory.CreateToastText02();
toastContent.Launch = "SampleLaunch";
toastContent.TextHeading.Text ="Sample Test"
toastContent.TextBodyWrap.Text ="Sample Test Content"
toastContent.Duration = ToastDuration.Long;
toastContent.Audio.Loop = true;
toastContent.Audio.Content = ToastAudioContent.LoopingAlarm;
ToastNotification toast1 = toastContent.CreateNotification();
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast1);

deferral.Complete();
```

Comment: Could you post some code or a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: i just change some Microsoft background task sample codes register a task setting time trigger is 15 mins and Task Run method show a toast.

Comment: And if you don't change the sample, does it work normally?

Comment: Also try to deploy the app in Release mode, close Visual Studio and then run and register the task separately, maybe there is a problem with the fact that it is run with debugger

Comment: If i don't change the sample, it's still not work after reboot device on windows 8.1 device

Comment: Then it more likely looks like a bug in the OS or the SDK itself. Unfortunately I have no Win 8.1 PC to test it on right now..

Comment: Have you confirmed that the background task has been registered or not after rebooting ?